# How To Left Join 2 Tables On 2 Different Databases?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have first database **(dbA)** with table like this, named **Username** :

```
+------------------+--------------+
| Username         | PhoneNumber  |
+------------------+--------------+
| jamesbond007     | 555-0074     |
| batmanbegins     | 555-0392     |
+------------------+--------------+
```

then, on the other side, I have **dbB** with table like this, named **PrivateMessage** :

```
+------------------+---------------------------------+
| Username         | Message                         |
+------------------+---------------------------------+
| jamesbond007     | I need new bond-girl            |
| batmanbegins     | thanks for the paycheck, Nolan  |
+------------------+---------------------------------+
```

now, how to combine this two tables from 2 different databases so the output will look like this :

```
+------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+
| Username         | PhoneNumber  | Message                         |
+------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+
| jamesbond007     | 555-0074     | I need new bond-girl            |
| batmanbegins     | 555-0392     | thanks for the paycheck, Nolan  |
+------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: since you have different collation, see my answer below.

Comment: dbA, dbB is a table not database.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can simply join the table of different database. You need to specify the database name in your `FROM` clause. To make it shorter, add an `ALIAS` on it,

```
SELECT  a.*,          -- this will display all columns of dba.`UserName`
      b.`Message`
FROM  dba.`UserName` a  -- or LEFT JOIN to show all rows whether it exists or not
      INNER JOIN dbB.`PrivateMessage` b    
         ON a.`username` = b.`username`
```

but some how, there are possiblities where-in a `username` won't have messages. In this case use `LEFT JOIN` if you want still to show all the records of `dba.Username`.

Reading from your comments, the tables have different `collation`. The work around on this is to specify `COLLATE` on your joined statements,

```
SELECT  a.*,          -- this will display all columns of dba.`UserName`
      b.`Message`
FROM  dba.`UserName` COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci a  
      LEFT JOIN dbB.`PrivateMessage` COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci b    
         ON a.`username` = b.`username`
```

you can change `latin1_swedish_ci` to whatever you want.

For more info on COLLATION, see this full list of

**[Character Sets and Collations in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html)**

---

If you have enough privilege to `ALTER` the tables, simply use this syntax to manually convert and match their collations,

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin2 COLLATE 'latin2_general_ci';
```

Comment: Answer above is to join tables in same database. You cannot join easly two tables from different databases

Comment: @fearis No, answer above is to join two tables from two different databases : `dba.UserName` and `dbB.PrivateMessage`. `dba` and `dbB` are databases and `UserName` and `PrivateMessage` are two tables (from different databases by the way).

However, answer above only works for database ON the SAME server

Answer (score 3):

Same as you would a normal table, except specifying the database:

```
SELECT dbA.Username, dbA.PhoneNumber, dbB.Message
   FROM dbA.Username LEFT JOIN dbB.PrivateMessage
   ON (dbA.UserName.Username = dbB.PrivateMessage.Username);
```

Things to look out for:

- LEFT JOIN will return all users, also those with no messages (use `INNER JOIN` to retrieve only users *with* messages)
- Users with multiple messages will appear multiple times (use aggregations and `GROUP BY` to only retrieve one message per user - you'll have to supply a criterion to choose the one message)
- You need query privileges on both databases (otherwise some user with privileges on both has to copy, e.g. periodically in crontab, a table or a subset of a table from a database to the other)
- Collations might not match. If this is the case, you have to change collation on one of the two tables using either [COLLATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.htm) or converting the field of one DB to the charset of the other with [CONVERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html): CONVERT(db.table.field USING Latin1), *which will prevent using indexes thus decreasing performances*. You can modify one of the two tables, but **verify** that you're not disrupting whatever query or application is using the `ALTER`'ed table (in a pinch, convert the whole database to well-tempered UTF8).
- `JOIN`s on text fields aren't very efficient even if you have INDEX on that in both tables; it would be better to have the Message table holding a unique, numeric *userid* to refer to the message owner. I understand that two different databases with different logics might not be conducive to this solution, but you could apply one of the above "tricks" ("*copy a table or subset thereof*") and export, periodically, a converted and ID'ed table from a DB to the other. That one periodical query would be expensive, but all subsequent JOINs would greatly benefit.

## Test run

This creates two tables with the same structure in two different databases, and joins them while in a *third* database.

> ```
> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
> Your MySQL connection id is 3
> Server version: 5.6.30 openSUSE package
>
> Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
> affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
> owners.
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
>
> mysql> CREATE DATABASE first_database;
> Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
>
> mysql> CREATE DATABASE second_database;
> Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> USE first_database;
> Database changed
> mysql> CREATE TABLE mytable ( x integer, t varchar(32) );
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> INSERT INTO mytable ( x, t ) VALUES ( 1, 'One in First Database' ), ( 2, 'Two in First Database' );
> Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
>
> mysql> USE second_database;
> Database changed
> mysql> CREATE TABLE mytable ( x integer, t varchar(32) );
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> INSERT INTO mytable ( x, t ) VALUES ( 1, 'One in Second Database' ), ( 3, 'Three in Second Database' );
> Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
>
> mysql> USE test;
> Database changed
> mysql> SELECT * FROM first_database.mytable LEFT JOIN second_database.mytable USING ( x );
> +------+-----------------------+------------------------+
> | x    | t                     | t                      |
> +------+-----------------------+------------------------+
> |    1 | One in First Database | One in Second Database |
> |    2 | Two in First Database | NULL                   |
> +------+-----------------------+------------------------+
> 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql>
> ```

Comment: I got this error message : #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: I'm getting same error as @Robert Hanson. Did you figure it out @Robert?

Comment: this will joint two tables in same database

Comment: No, @fearis - it will join a table in dbA to a table in dbB, dbA and dbB being two different databases. If you tried this and it did not work, you can ask a question (or add a comment to specify what did not work in my example).

Answer (score 0):

The SQL for this is rather easy...

```
SELECT A.Username, A.PhoneNumber, B.Message
FROM dbA.Username as A
INNER JOIN dbB.PrivateMessage as B ON A.Username = B.Username
```

...assuming you can access both databases within your connection.

If you cannot access them, you have to work on a different approach (like copying one table to the other database before querying or something similar).

Comment: I got this error message from your code : #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: Then your tables have different collations, so you cannot join them. You first have to even them out in order to execute this query, one way would be to `ALTER TABLE dbA.Username CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET uft8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; ALTER TABLE dbB.PrivateMessage CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET uft8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`. Keep in mind this changes the character set of the tables, so please do this only if you a) know what you're doing and b) if it doesn't affect other critical applications.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
SELECT * FROM dbA.Username JOIN dbB.PrivateMessage USING(Username);
```