# uploading tables of two database of differernt site in one database

Tags: phpmyadmin

i want to upload tables of two database of differernt site in one database in phpmyadmin because it has the Privileges of only one database so is there any problem if i will combine those two and upload
thank you

Comment: Elaborate your question with specific problem and share your code if you have done something

Answer (score 0):

May you try to explain clearly What do you want.I do  not understand your aim clearly.But in slq you can use join method for this problem such as inner or left join may help you.[How To Left Join 2 Tables On 2 Different Databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685193/how-to-left-join-2-tables-on-2-different-databases)